# EntityFramework работа с базой в библиотеке

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Я только начинаю вникать в EntityFramework и у меня сразу возникло множество вопросов. Вот некоторые из них

**Как рулить базой через отдельную библиотеку в проекте?**

Сейчас я делаю WPF приложение, завтра я захочу сделать WinForms, а потом и вообще подключить веб интерфейс или консоль. То есть нужно модель приложения вынести в отдельную библиотеку. Что я и сделал. Для обкатки использую консольное приложение. Во первых, при каких либо манипуляциях с `DbSet<>`, даже неявных (то есть при вызове методов, в которых что то выполняется с `DbSet<>`), решение не компилируется, говорит что к моему консольному приложению нужно цеплять EntityFramework.

- **Получается, что мне надо цеплять EntityFramework к каждому UI проекту?**
- **Как это обойти?**

При этом `AppConfig` используется из того проекта, в котором я использую свою библиотеку. Может это и логично, но я хочу иметь централизованные настройки, то есть `AppConfig` в составе моей библиотеки, работающей с базой. **Как это сделать?**